Microsoft blob storage file download
I am trying to download multiple files from a azure blob storage. I have successful download one file with the specific file name, but in the python applicantion i am trying to make, i dont know the specific name of the files, i only know parts of the name.
The naming of the files is: ID-YYYYMMDD-HHmm
I want it to download all files with specific ID and Year, Mounth and Day
I have found a way of listing all files on the blob storage, but that takes around 30 mins to run.
I was hoping i could use the * for the last part of the naming, but it does not work :D
ID-YYYYMMDD-*

So is there are better way to download multiple files when getting a list of all the files and going thougth the list and then download based on the naming in the list?

Post your code. You need to specify a prefix, not wildcards. Cloud storage in general has no folders or wildcards, whether it's AWS S3 or Azure Blob Storage. Such things just don't scale to buckets with millions of objects. A bucket contains a flat list of files. The fast way to list lots of files it to perform a prefix search. Folders are emulated by specifying a "separator" character, by default "". Folder searches are essentially prefix searches for anything starting with the full "path". You can specify - as the path separator and get a list of all files in the YYYYMMDD "folder".

Have you checked List Blobs with Python? You should be able to use container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with="ID-YYYYMMDD-")

@PanagiotisKanavos
The "name_starts_with" does help alot.
Are there more options to the list_blobs function? lets say an option there it only takes the YYYYMMDD and finds all the matching to that?

Read the docs to understand how blob storage really works. I already explained there are no wildcards in either AWS S3, Azure Blobs or any other cloud storage and why. You can either work with prefixes or tags. Any other kind of search requires retrieving all file name and filtering them on the client. Behind the scenes, the cloud service splits the bucket/container in partitions. When you search for something with a prefix, the service can use several workers to scan only the partitions that contain that prefix. Without a prefix, everything has to be scanned. Tags work as a kind of index.

Cloud storage simply doesn't behave like disk storage. For example, the sort order implied by the name also matters. When you list a large number of files you can page the results by specifying that the next "page" should start after a specific item. That means you can ask for the latest items for an ID by date by specifying the last ID-Date you've processed. You can't ask for new files for all IDs just by specifying the date though


Is there a better way to download multiple files when getting a list of all the files, going through the list, and then downloading based on the naming in the list?

I agree with Panagiotis Kanavos's comment, there are no wildcards in Azure Blob Storage. Instead, you can use prefixes or tags to filter the results.
You can list the blobs with prefix by container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with="ID-YYYYMMDD-"), which will make you list the blobs with specific names.
In my environment, I have stored a list of files in Azure Blob Storage.
Portal:

Now, if I want to list the files which start like sample, it will list the sample starting items, and it will download in my environment.
Code:
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobPrefix

connection_string = "xxxxx"
container_name = "test"
local_path = r"C:\Users\Documents\input"
prefix="sample"

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

blobs = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with=prefix)

for blob in blobs:
    print(blob.name)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob.name)
    download_path = f"{local_path}/{blob.name}"
    with open(download_path, "wb") as download_file:
        download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
        download_file.write(download_stream.readall())

Output and Files:


Another suggestion is to use tags. You can add Blob index tags to all your files with specific keys and values and you can use the find_blobs_by_tags to get the list of files with queried tags.
Code:
query = "\"Content\"='image'" 
blob_list = container_client.find_blobs_by_tags(filter_expression=query)

for blob in blob_list: 
  print(blob.name)
  blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob.name)
  download_path = f"{local_path}/{blob.name}"
  with open(download_path, "wb") as download_file:
    download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
    download_file.write(download_stream.readall())

The above code will list the files with specific tags and download all listed files.
Reference:
Use blob index tags to manage and find data with Python - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn

Do list blobs with a name starts with. Then loop through the blob list using asyncio for the downloading portion.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-download-python#download-blobs-asynchronously
If it's still too slow for your liking, you need to either think about how you're managing the blob paths... maybe do a folder for each month/year? Or manage using blob tags? Then go back and do the above. asyncio should speed things up nicely.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
